# Using a Subclass to use as parameter

Tags: c#, oop, subclass

```
public class Animal {}
public class Cow: Animal {}
public class JerseyCow: Cow {}
```

Hello. So, I want to be able to pass a Subclass/Type as a parameter so that the method below works. After experimenting and researching, I can't find any that could make this work.

```
private double aveProf(Type xxxxxx)
        {
            double count = 0;
            double sum = 0;
            double ratio = 0;
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Animal> animal in farmAnimalDict)
            {
                if (animal.Value.GetType() == typeof(xxxxxx))
                {
                    sum += animal.Value.getProfit();
                    count++;
                }
            }
            ratio = sum / count;
            
            return ave;
        }
```

So I want to be able to use it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(aveProf(JerseyCow) + aveProf(Cow));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use generics:

```cs
private double aveProf<TAnimal>()
    where TAnimal: Animal // constrain it to only the Animal base class 
                          // which is necessary to use .getProfit()
{
    double count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double ratio = 0;

    // using TAnimal and the dictionary's .Values property lets us
    // simplify the loop and loop body
    foreach (var animal in farmAnimalDict.Values.OfType<TAnimal>())
    {
        sum += animal.getProfit();
        count++;
    }


    // I've assumed that the result should be 0 where there aren't
    // any animals. This is to prevent a DivideByZeroException.
    ratio = count > 0
        ? sum / count
        : 0;
    
    return ratio;
}
```

Usage:

```cs
double dogAvg = aveProf<Dog>();
double sheepAvg = aveProf<Sheep>();
double cowAvg = aveProf<Cow>();
```

---

You can use simplify it using LINQ too:

```cs
private double aveProf<TAnimal>()
    where TAnimal: Animal
{
   return farmAnimalDict.Values
       .OfType<TAnimal>()
       .Select(a => a.getProfit())
        // if there are no animals of this type, we should default to 0
       .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
       .Average();
}
```

Usage:

```cs
double dogAvg = aveProf<Dog>();
double sheepAvg = aveProf<Sheep>();
double cowAvg = aveProf<Cow>();
```

Comment: Yeah, ratio was a mistake, I was mainly focused on using the class type as a parameter so I can use this method on calculating the average of specific subclasses within the animal dictionary. Basically, I want to be able to use aveProf() and pass the subclass as a parameter so that I can calculate the average of specific subclasses within the animal dictionary. I want to be able to aveProf(Cow). aveProf(JerseyCow) or aveProf(Sheep) passing the subclass as a parameter with one method. Not sure if this is possible.

Comment: @SapphireReg So what exactly is wrong with the options I provided above?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this. But I could be wrong. Let's say I have 3 subclasses under animals; namely Dog, Sheep, and Cow. With the options above, I have to create 3 separate methods to get the average of each class. Am I understanding it, right? Whereas I'm looking for a way to write one method that would use the type class as a parameter so that I use one method for getting the average for all 3. Not sure If I'm making sense.

Comment: @SapphireReg No, that's not how the method above works. Example: `double dogAvg = aveProf<Dog>(); double avgSheep = aveProf<Sheep>(); double cowAvg = aveProf<Cow>();` does exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for this. I understand the syntax better now. Though, I'm running into a 'TAnimal' does not have a definition of Value error. Might have to read more into this. Cheers.

Comment: @SapphireReg Ah the `Value` part was my bad. It's because I changed to using `farmAnimalDict.Values` so we had an `IEnumerable<Animal>` instead of an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Animal>>`, meaning that the value we use is just the `Animal` and not the `KeyValuePair<int, Animal>` so `.Value` isn't needed anymore. I just forgot to remove it.